# Error with pgAdmin III and pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, authentication, pgadmin, pgadmin-3

I have a problem with my Pgadmin3.. I used to use the last year, but this year I can't connect with the localhost server with pgadmin

This is the message error:

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL on
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

My `pg_hba.conf` file have this content:

```
TYPE       DATABASE USER                ADDRESS                 METHOD
local      all                          all                     trust
```

I can connect without problems with psql. My user is postgres and my pass is postgres too.

I have information in the database, i don't have idea what's happen.

My OS is Linux Lubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

Look at the first column `TYPE`, from [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

> **local** This record matches connection attempts using Unix-domain sockets. Without a record of this type, Unix-domain socket connections are disallowed.
>
> **host** This record matches connection attempts made using TCP/IP. host records match either SSL or non-SSL connection attempts.

Your type is `local`, but your error message indicates you're trying to connect to `127.0.0.1` which is an IP address. You either need to connect using unix sockets without an ip-address (no `-h` in psql) or change the `type` to `host`.

From the [docs on PgAdminIII](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/connect.html)

> The host is the IP address of the machine to contact, or the fully qualified domain name. **On Unix based systems, the address field may be left blank to use the default PostgreSQL Unix Domain Socket** on the local machine, or be set to an alternate path containing a PostgreSQL socket. If a path is entered, it must begin with a “/”. The port number may also be specified.